# apply column style to table body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created the following table in html. I want to apply a style to table body elements in column which i have added a css class. But the style should not apply to header column. only to body column.

Here for a example i have add CSS class called "body-right". The result what i want is all the table body elements in column "Value" should "right align" except header column. How to achieve this in css.
Thanks a lot.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Criteria</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td class="body-right">Value</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>GGGGGG</td>
            <td>35.63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XYZ</td>
            <td>HHHHH</td>
            <td>68.26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MNP</td>
            <td>KKKKK</td>
            <td>45.26</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can use `th` for table head and apply style to `td` demo - http://jsfiddle.net/7b1gd6kf/

Comment: what if there are more columns and i want to apply to multiple columns. then i have to add style to them also. i want a way to avoid that. thats why i said that , i want to apply to body elements where ever i add a class to header column.

Comment: then you can use `nth-child` http://jsfiddle.net/7b1gd6kf/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
tbody td:nth-of-type(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

**Example**

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font: 14px verdana;
}

td {
  padding: 0.2em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody td:nth-of-type(3) {
  text-align: right;
  background: yellow;
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Criteria</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td class="body-right">Value</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>GGGGGG</td>
            <td>35.63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XYZ</td>
            <td>HHHHH</td>
            <td>68.26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MNP</td>
            <td>KKKKK</td>
            <td>45.26</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: with this solution i have to apply this to all the columns i want to change. if i also want to apply to 4th and 6 th columns, i have to apply separately to them.

Comment: Correct, you could add the additional columns to the CSS as a comma-separated list:  `tbody td:nth-of-type(3), tbody td:nth-of-type(4), tbody td:nth-of-type(6)`

Comment: Oh, you want the columns to inherit the class based on the thead row?  I don't think that's possible in CSS.

Comment: aren't there any way to avoid that. is there any way to achieve this a using a class??

Comment: You can't set a class on an element and have it apply to other elements that aren't children of that element.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this by specifying inline style for the header section seperately.
or make a little change in the css 
like

> **thead .body-right { text-align:right; }**